# Angular.js $scope.$on initial value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular.js $scope.$on for listening for events from my service(event got triggered on service data change).

I use the following code snippet:

```
$scope.people = contacts.people;
$scope.$on('contacts-changed', () => {
    $scope.people = contacts.people;
});
```

Is there any way to extend angular to avoid the first line and trigger  $scope.$on('contacts-changed') or similar by default on the time of event bind?
I was looking in angular.js decorators but not sure how can I decorate $scope to add $scope.$bind or similar method

Ideas?

Comment: Actually this can be solved by some kind of dirty hack with global $bind function $bind($scope, 'event-name', handler) or with $bind located in $rootScope, but I'm looking for a more angular-friendly solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the solution is so simple, but you need to think outside of the box. Move the event callback block into a function and just run it when the controller loads, after the event binding.

See this:

```
function handlePeople() {
    $scope.people = contacts.people;
}
$scope.$on('contacts-changed', handlePeople);
handlePeople();
```

You can also keep the original code and do a trigger manually.

Comment: Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: I wanted some convenient wrapper($scope.$bind) to reduce code bloating and simplify things as I have tons of such calls and do not want to declare functions for such simple things. Basically I just need to put $scope.$bind in each $scope(and not to $rootScope) which will act exactly as $scope.$on but will be self invokable for the first time.

Comment: Declaring functions for such things (simple or not) IS the recommended way to do it: https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#named-vs-anonymous-functions If you don't want to do it like that, sounds like you've answered your own question then, right?

Comment: But why would I need a function if there should be a simpler solution for this particular task, I'm not going to reuse this code or do something else with it, my only desire here is to do very simple thing(bind service data to my controller's $scope and track changes in service data) with minimum of code from my side

Comment: @sfireman if you have `tons of such calls` sounds like you are over using events and probably don't need a lot of them

Answer (score 0):

Temporally went with the following solution:

```
$rootScope.$bind = (bindName, bindHandler) => {
    $rootScope.$on(bindName, bindHandler);
    bindHandler();
};
```

But I'd want to replace it so I could use $scope instead of $rootScope and without defining this in each $scope...
I could try to use $scope._ *proto* _ but it seems _ *proto* _ is deprecated